# Writing multiple column vectors to output in Scilab

Tags: csv, multiple-columns, scilab

I see some overly complicated examples of how this might be done in Matlab, but how about Scilab? I am successful at writing a single column vector to an output.csv, but how do I write multiple column vectors to the same output.csv. The code which prints a single column vector is below, and it shows the other column vectors (rate, cumulative) which I would like to have printed to the output.csv as well. How to do this?

Thanks.

```html
//import csv data
data_import = evstr(csvRead('input.csv', ','));

//extraction of columns and definition of variables
time=data_import(:,1)
rate=data_import(:,2)
cumulative=data_import(:,3)

//multiplication of time in hours by 2
timetimestwo=time*2

//export csv and print new variable
csvWrite(timetimestwo,'output.csv',' ');
```

*note: I since added a way to print the three columns to a single column, but I still want to print as a 3 column matrix, and I'm not sure why the three columns aren't being split up. I did this:

```html
M = [timetimestwo; rate; cumulative]


for i = 1:3
    csvWrite(M,'output.csv',',','.')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolons make it one big column matrix, you should use comma's. In the illustration I below you can see the concept, kind of....

```
|                                   |   |[timetimestwo(1)],[rate(1)],[cumulative(1)]|       
|                                   |   |[timetimestwo(2)],[rate(2)],[cumulative(2)]|
|[timetimestwo],[rate],[cumulative] | = |[timetimestwo(3)],[rate(3)],[cumulative(3)]|
|                                   |   |[timetimestwo(4)],[rate(4)],[cumulative(4)]|
|                                   |   |[timetimestwo(5)],[rate(5)],[cumulative(5)]|
```

A working example of your problem would thus be:

```
//import csv data
data_import = evstr(csvRead('input.csv', ','));

//extraction of columns and definition of variables
time=data_import(:,1)
rate=data_import(:,2)
cumulative=data_import(:,3)

//multiplication of time in hours by 2
timetimestwo=time*2

M=[timetimestwo,rate,cumulative]

//export csv and print new variable
csvWrite(M,'output.csv',' ');
```